Modify SMPS for control with PIC
I'm pretty new in designing things with SMPS, so I want to take an already designed and working circuit, but I want to control the output with a pic, so I can use it for my circuits.  Currently I'm using PIC16F18076.

This is a very common design for a 12 V, 10 A SMPS, and I think two ideas for controlling the output, the most “correct” one, is changing the mosfet controller, and the other one is this circuit:

What do you think about the second one? Will it work? It will give me problems? If I do the first one, what should I consider? Thanks.


You'll introduce extra delay in the feedback loop which might cause instability. 2) You can only adjust output down by so much before the primary aux winding can no longer supply the controller...


A fully self-powered power supply doesn't have much adjustable range: consider what happens when the aux winding drops below the operating minimum of U1 (8V or so).
Running feedback through the MCU isn't a good idea: it defeats the purpose of the analog system, and puts hard real-time demands on its programming.  If the circuit starts up at all, which, it might just blow up while the MCU is still booting, who knows.
Better to do it this way:

The aux supply is needed for wide output range.  This keeps the controller and MCU running even at zero output, an important feature for an adjustable bench supply.  It can be an off-the-shelf module (but high-isolation dual-output versions might be hard to find?), or made with a smaller transformer and LinkSwitch or the like (single-IC offline regulator).  Or you can make a whole 'nother UC3842/3 circuit, it's not a big deal.
The MCU should reads VO (via divider) passively, and set a voltage on R_D that tweaks the setpoint of U4.  This doesn't disturb compensation, the loop remains closed and steady, it's just running at a different setpoint.  Even if the MCU crashes, the worst that can happen is the output gets stuck at [DAC_MAXVAL], nothing blows up (well, maybe a load that wasn't expecting it..), everything runs normally otherwise.  The sample rate doesn't need to be much, either: you might run at some kHz just to keep transitions smooth, but it could be 100s or even 10s of Hz (coincident with a display or serial output update, perhaps).
Some EMI improvements may be desirable.  The direct output of a flyback tends to have high ripple -- full peak switching current into the capacitors' ESR.  ESR is fairly low these days, but it can still be the better part of a volt, and you'll see that in everything you probe (again, assuming this is a bench supply sort of application).  An additional LC (say 1uH and 100s uF) will simply clean that up.
There should be a "Y" capacitor between primary and secondary, as well.  The position varies, depending on transformer construction, heatsinking, etc.; it may be better between primary DC GND and output VO-, or to the line as shown, or to earth/chassis (assuming a 3-wire cable).
There may also be ringing on the rectifier, which Rsn/Csn can help with.  This is the inverse situation as D2/C7/R8 treats; instead of primary turn-off transient, it's to deal with primary turn-on.   Exact values depend on leakage inductance and D4 capacitance.
